# Rails calling User record from Friends model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I've built a simple `Friend` model, which allows `Users` to have multiple friends. Here's what that looks like:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
```

Each friend record just has an `id`, `user_id` and `friend_id`. The `user_id` is the id of the user it belongs to and the `friend_id` is the id of user they are befriending.

**Here's my problem**
I'm not quite sure how to display a list of a particular user's friends. `@user.friends` will give me a list of all the friend records they have, but not the user accounts of those friends.

For instance, I am trying to build a `show` page for the `friends` controller:

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
def show
  @user = current_user
end
```

SHOW.HTML.ERB

```
<% if @user.friends.count > 0 %>
  <% @user.friends.each do |friend| %>
    <div class="entry">
      <%= friend.username %>
```

This does not work because `friend` in this case does not have `username`. I need to do something like this in my controller:

```
@friend = User.find_by_id(friend.friend_id)
```

But I'm not sure how I would call that in my view in the @user.friends loop. Any thoughts appreciated. Let me know if I need to be more clear.

**UPDATE**
I've updated my `User` model like so:

```
has_many :friends, :include => :user
has_many :friended_users, :through => :friends, :source => :user, :uniq => true
```

However, when I run `@user.friended_users` it's giving me the `user_id`s (which is the same as @user) rather than `friend_id`s.

How can I tweak that relationship so it's linking to the `friend_id` rather than `user_id`?

The more I think about it, I think I may not have set up the relationship properly in the first place. Maybe a `User` should `has_many :users, through => 'friends'`, but that doesn't really make sense...

**UPDATE**
I've updated my models based on @twooface's input:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :users
```

I'm just not sure what my Friends table should look like. I assume it should have a primary key and a `user_id`? If I create a friendship and friend record, I can do `friendship.user` and `friendship.friend` and get the correct results, but `user.friends` gives me an empty hash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your relations are built a bit wrong. Try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
  # This class has :user_id and :friend_id
```

Then everything will be simpler. Every user will have an array of friends that will be just users.

```
User.first.friends
```

Will return an array of Users that this User friends.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Correct me if I'm wrong, so the Friend class has :user_id and :friend_id, and the Friendship class also has :user_id and :friend_id?

Comment: @twoface, I've update my models based on what you said, but I'm just not sure what Friends should look like (see updates above). I'd appreciate any advice; thanks!

Comment: There is no no Friend class (sort of, it's an instance of User class) so You have only objects of User class and objects of Friendships between them.