# How to get single attribute from array in a has_many :through association (User/Friend model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

In my User model I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"

  has_many :pending_friends, 
   :through => :friendships, 
   :conditions => "status = 'pending'", 
   :foreign_key => "user_id", 
   :source => :friend

  has_many :requested_friends, 
   :through => :friendships,
   :source => :friend, 
   :conditions => "status = 'requested'"

  def friends
    direct_friends | inverse_friends
  end
```

In my Friendship model I have the following:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```

In my view I have created an array of each of the users' friends, shown below. This code works and populates the array with all the data from the friends' "User" database model attributes.

```
  User.first.friends
```

However, I want to be able to call the users' friend's name's. So, for example, shouldn't I be able to do something like this?

```
    User.first.friends.map(&:name)
```

How do I get an array containing just the friend's name's, instead of all the friend's user attributes? I would also appreciate if anyone could tell me why .first is used (I got that from here: [Rails calling User record from Friends model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523037/rails-calling-user-record-from-friends-model)), as it doesn't just get the first instance of the User's friends (it gets all the instances). And why does just doing:

```
 User.friends
```

return an empty array?

Answer (score 5):

Try method [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
User.first.friends.pluck(:name)
```

You should use `first` method to retrieve one object from table. The User is table with a lot of users.